# read method of ItemReader & stepExecutionListner's custom implementation is not called

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

read method of ItemReader & stepExecutionListner's custom implementation is not called. The basic code structure is as below -

```
public class myCustomReader implements ItemReader<List<String>>, StepExecutionListener {

    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this);
    
    private List<String> dataList;
    
    @Override
    synchronized public List<String> read()
            throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        logger.info("read called");
        
        dataList.add("A");
        dataList.add("B");
        dataList.add("C");
        dataList.add("D");
        dataList.add("E");
        
        return dataList;
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        logger.info("beforeStep called");   
        dataList.add("A");
        dataList.add("B");
        dataList.add("C");
        dataList.add("D");
        dataList.add("E");
    }
    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        logger.info("afterStep called");        
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

}
```

The appropriate configurations are done in the xml files. The reader is getting called and prints only beforeStep() & afterStep() logs, no logs from read() method. Since there's no data passed to processor from reader, processor gets called but doesnt do anything.
Please help me identify the root cause and fix it.

```
<batch:job id="jobId" restartable="false"
    job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="stepdId">
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="batchTaskExecuter">
            <batch:chunk reader="myCustomReader"
                 
                writer="myCustomWriter"
                commit-interval="10" 
                >
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Edit: added config.

Edit2: I tried removing & adding 'synchornized' for read() method, without any change. When I remove stepExecutionListener and keep only ItemReader in the implementation, then only read method gets called.

I am expecting read() method logs to get printed, i.e. read() method should get called.

Comment: 99% sure that the problem is with the config. You need to explicitly define reader for `Step`. Did you do that in config? You can attach your config to the question, so it will be much easier for others to help you

Comment: Thank you @DanilaZharenkov I have added the config too but the reader is getting called that I am sure of, from the logs.